# Does''couldn't'' mean "the subjunctive mood" in the following sentence?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, subjunctives

Does "couldn't" mean "the subjunctive mood" in the following sentence?

> I couldn't make myself understood in English.

Comment: *Could* here is the ordinary past form of *can*, and there's nothing in the form or content of the sentence itself to suggest that the past form is employed to mark conditionality or irreality or politeness or anything except past tense.

Comment: No, this is nothing like a subjunctive which uses a plain (infinitival) verb-form, as in _It is vital that I **be** kept informed_. But here, the modal verb "could" is the past tense of "can", so the meaning here is that you were unable to make yourself understood.

Comment: But a clause added to your sentence can affect the meaning of **couldn't**.  "I couldn't solve a quadratic equation even if my life depended on it".

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments. I realized that ''couldn't'' in the sentence doesn't mean the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB and BillJ comment, there is nothing in the sentence to suggest the subjunctive mood.  It is just a simple statement of ability.

However as TRomano mentions you can add more to the sentence to make it subjunctive, by turning it into a hypothetical case.

> I couldn't make myself understood in English even if my life depended on it"

Comment: Many grammarians nowadays consider the subjunctive to be a type of clause construction, not a mood form, headed by a plain (infinitival) form of the verb as in _I demand that you **pay** me immediately_. I would simply call your example a 'remote conditional'.

Comment: You explained to me the proper usage of "could" and gave me the practical example. Thank you for your kindness.